# 3 types of modulus, 3 types of soundwaves in solids

Tags: solid-state-physics, acoustics, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, solid-mechanics

I noticed there are 3 types of [elastic moduli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_modulus) and 3 types of waves in solids in [linear elasticty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity#Elastic_wave):

- [Young modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus) that describes tensile stiffness (the velocity of a [flexural wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexural_rigidity) is defined only by the Young modulus).
- [shear modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_modulus) about shearing stiffness (the velocity of a [shear wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_wave) is defined only by the shear modulus).
- [bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) that is about compression stiffness (the velocity of a [longitudinal wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_wave) is defined only by the bulk modulus).

Are the velocities of 3 types of waves dependent on the value of 3 types of modulus? Are the above points correct?

Comment: Sadly, it is worse than that. In general, the stiffness (or compliance) tensor connecting stress to strain can have 81 coefficients, although crystal symmetry tends to reduce this. Cubic and isotropic systems have only 3. Triclinic crystals have many more...

Comment: What coefficient do you mean? What are Triclinic crystals? What is Cubic system? I know what isotropic means but rest of your comment I dont understand.If you could teach me what these things mean I would be super grateful.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law is a good place to start.

Comment: Already read that,I have no idea what 81 coefficients you meant.Do you mean there is 81 types of modulus? 81 types of waves in solids?

Comment: And a longitudinal wave in a rod would depend on Young's modulus.

Comment: The stress or strain tensor is 3x3. To connect one 3x3 tensor to another 3x3 tensor requires 81 coefficients. Now, symmetry reduces that to 21 possibly distinct entries. High symmetry (cubic, isotropic) reduces it to 3. Crystals that are not high symmetry have somewhere between 3 and 21 distinct coefficients, depending on the specific symmetries exhibited by the crystal.

Comment: The 3 moduli you mentioned are all inter-related.  There are really only two independent parameters:  the Young's modulus and the Poisson ratio.  The bulk modulus and the shear modulus are determined from these.

Comment: Wow! I didnt know that Chester Miller,thats extremly interesting.So you are saying for homogenous isotropic material,once I know Young modulus and Poisson ratio,I can then calculate bulk and shear modulus?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying.

Comment: Bulk modulus = $\frac{3E}{(1-2\nu)}$.  Shear modulus = $\frac{E}{2(1+\nu)}$

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a little bit confused, so let me try to explain things slightly more systematically.

1. It is important to understand that there are actually many different types of waves, not three and not four. However, many waves are enabled by specific geometric features of the problem at hand, so one usually separates so-called body waves from all the other kinds of waves. Body waves can propagate in an infinite elastic space. There are exactly 2 types of body waves: longitudinal and shear waves. Generally speaking, in anisotropic materials, the velocity of these waves can depend on the direction of propagation and these waves themselves can couple to each other. However, assuming isotropic materials, you will have them uncoupled and their velocities will be direction-independent and given by
   $$
   c_1^2=\frac{\lambda+2\mu}{\rho},\quad c_2^2=\frac{\mu}{\rho},
   $$
   where $c_1$ is the longitudinal wave speed and $c_2$ is the shear wave speed. You can see that the shear wave speed is proportional to the square root of the shear modulus. However, the velocity of longitudinal waves is not related to one specific modulus.
2. Any isotropic material can be characterized by exactly two modulae. $\lambda$ and $\mu$ that I used just above are often called Lame parameters. In some situations people prefer to use other modulae too. Modulae most commonly used for isotropic materials are:
   $$
     E=\frac{\mu(3\lambda+2\mu)}{\lambda+\mu},\quad
     \nu=\frac{\lambda}{2(\lambda+\mu)},\quad
     \kappa=\lambda+\frac{2}{3}\mu.
   $$
   $\kappa$ is the bulk modulus, it characterizes stiffness for volume deformations; $E$ the Young modulus, it predicts the stiffness of a thin bar, and $\nu$ the Poisson ratio that characterizes how much thin bar contracts transversally when it is stretched.
3. Note the emphasis on specific geometries in the last two examples. Some combinations of modulae were introduced precisely because they are convenient to use for specific geometries. Since thin bars are convenient objects for testing, a number of parameters are defined with thin bar testing in mind. In this sense, you may find it instructive that velocity of sound in a thin elastic bar is given by
   $$
     c_{\mathrm{bar}}^2=\frac{E}{\rho},
   $$
   i.e. that the Young modulus is directly proportional to the square of velocity of longitudinal waves in bars. However, outside of this specific geometry, the interpretation of Young modulus becomes much less intuitive.